# Having an issue extending Data.Functor.Foldable

Tags: haskell, recursion-schemes

This question uses the concepts/imports from http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-4.0/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html

I'm trying to extend this to thread a given monad through a catamorphism. Here is the code that I'm trying to compile:

```
class (Monad m, Foldable t) => FoldableM m t where
  distM :: Base t (m a) -> m (Base t a)

  cataM :: (Base t a -> m a) -> t -> m a 
  cataM f = join . liftM f . distM . fmap (cataM f) . project
```

But the call to `distM` in `cataM` for some reason can't figure out to use the same `t`.

The error I get is:

```
Expected type: Base t (m a) -> m (Base t a)
Actual type: Base t0 (m a) -> m (Base t0 a)
```

I made the code a bit less sexy and a bit easier to debug here:

```
cataM :: forall a . (Base t a -> m a) -> t -> m a
cataM f t = join d
  where
  a :: Base t t
  a = project t

  b :: Base t (m a)
  b = fmap (cataM f) a

  g :: Base t (m a) -> m (Base t a)
  g = distM

  c :: m (Base t a)
  c = g b

  d :: m (m a)
  d = liftM f c
```

The definition of `g` is what causes the issue.

EDIT: The problem as I understand it is that when it calls `distM` it only has `Base t` to infer the type from, so it cannot work out `t`. This is frustrating, since I know what `t` I want to use. In fact, I think if I could supply the type arguments to `distM` manually it would fix the problem, but I don't think that's possible.

Here is a solution but I'm not happy with it:

```
class (Monad m, Foldable t) => FoldableM m t where
  distM :: t -> Base t (m a) -> m (Base t a)

  cataM :: forall a . (Base t a -> m a) -> t -> m a
  cataM f = join . liftM f . distM (undefined :: t) . fmap (cataM f) . project
```

EDIT 2: Cool to learn about `Proxy` (thanks Antal). I've been Haskelling for years now and just learnt yet another new thing. I love this language. The solution I'm using is:

```
class (Monad m, Foldable t) => FoldableM m t where
  distM :: proxy t -> Base t (m a) -> m (Base t a)

  cataM :: forall a . (Base t a -> m a) -> t -> m a
  cataM f = join . liftM f . distM (Proxy :: Proxy t) . fmap (cataM f) . project
```

Comment: Could it be that you need `ScopedTypeVariables`?

Comment: Unfortunately not :( the type variable `t` is scoped already because we are in a type-class definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Base t` is a type family, so GHC can't know `t` from `Base t`. There's no way to get `distM` to work without mentioning `t`.

Comment: No way at all? :( 
I guess I'll have to add `t` to `distM` as a ghost parameter. Annoying.

Comment: @Will: The problem is that `Base` may not be injective; consider what would happen if `Base S1 T1 ~ A` and `Base S2 T2 ~ A`.  Also, you can use the `Proxy` approach to make it explicit that the parameter is just for typing (probably with `-XKindPolymorphism`): `data Proxy t = Proxy`, and then `distM :: Proxy t -> ...`.

Comment: If you do use a proxy, perhaps use the signature `distM :: g t -> ...` instead of `Proxy t`?  There are a few different proxies around, and this will work with all of them instead of limiting to just one particular proxy.